# Coastsat not running when try on jupyter

Tags: python

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 16
     14 import pandas as pd
     15 from datetime import datetime
---> 16 from coastsat import SDS_download, SDS_preprocess, SDS_shoreline, SDS_tools, SDS_transects

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coastsat'
```

I have not try anything

Comment: It seems there is some kind of issue with your Jupyter installation. 
show us your code and  screenshot of the window

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't installed [coastStat library](https://github.com/kvos/CoastSat).

Using above link you should download the repository.

On your Anaconda environment cd into the folder where You have downloaded coastStat library.

Run below code:

```bash
conda create -n coastsat
conda activate coastsat
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas -y
conda install -c conda-forge earthengine-api scikit-image matplotlib astropy notebook -y
pip install pyqt5 imageio-ffmpeg
conda activate coastsat
```

[More info](https://github.com/kvos/CoastSat?tab=readme-ov-file#installation) regarding Installation.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is occurring, is indicating that you didn't install the package(coastsat).

You can read the installation instructions on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kvos/CoastSat?tab=readme-ov-file#installation), or follow these instructions:

### Instructions

1. Cloning the repo

Open a terminal and run the following command to clone the repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/kvos/CoastSat.git
```

If you don't have git installed, you can just download the repo zipfile and extract it from this link [here](https://github.com/kvos/CoastSat/archive/refs/heads/master.zip).

2. Creating a new environment called `coastsat`:

Create a new environment named `coastsat` with all the required packages by entering these commands in succession:

```
conda create -n coastsat
conda activate coastsat
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas -y
conda install -c conda-forge earthengine-api scikit-image matplotlib astropy notebook -y
pip install pyqt5 imageio-ffmpeg
```

All the required packages have now been installed and are self-contained in an environment called coastsat. Always make sure that the environment is activated with:

```
conda activate coastsat
```